Laravel 8+, pass request into route manually, is it possible?
I have a Laravel 8 project. I have a route:
Route::get('/route-path', 'Client\SomeController@someMethod')->name('MyRouteName');

And it's implementation in SomeController
public function someMethod(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $field_1 = $request->f1;
    $field_2 = $request->f2;

    return view('my_view', compact('field_1', 'field_2'));
}

I'd like to redirect my site into MyRouteName route, but I'd like to create request manually:
$request = new Illuminate\Http\Request();
$request->request->add([
    'f1' => 'value_1',
    'f2' => 'value_2',
]);

return redirect()->route('MyRouteName', $request);

Is it possible to pass fake request this way? If not, how to achieve it?
I'm inside of writing larger part of code, at this point I cannot test.

In Laravel, you cannot directly pass a Request object to the redirect()->route() method. The redirect()->route() method expects parameters that correspond to route parameters, not a full Request object.
However, you can pass query parameters or simply add the data to the redirect URL. Here’s how you can achieve that:
Option 1: Pass Parameters Directly
You can pass the parameters directly in the redirect like this:
return redirect()->route('MyRouteName', [
'f1' => 'value_1',
'f2' => 'value_2',
]);
Option 2: Using Query Parameters
If your route is expecting query parameters, you can add them as such:
public function index(Request $request)
{
// Get the 'q' query parameter from the request
$query = $request->query('q');
// Or you can use:
$query = $request->input('q');

// Use the query parameter
return view('search-results', compact('query'));

}
Option 3: Using Flash Data
If you need to preserve the values in the session and access them in your controller, you can use flash data:
$request->session()->flash('f1', 'value_1');
$request->session()->flash('f2', 'value_2');

Thank you so much, I've chosen first method, thanks! :)

The code in option 1 and 2 is exactly the same...
